# Using LDAP/AD to find mailing lists user is subscribed to

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am currently looking into getting a list of mailing distribution lists that a user is subscribed to. I have never used Active Directories before, and after reading into various answers here and on MSDN, I'm very confused.

I have my query set up like this:

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
search.Filter = String.Format("LDAP://CN={0},OU=<value here>,DC=<value>...", userName);
search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
if(result != null)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. What does the SearchRoot property within DirectorySearcher do? Do I need to set that up to have this query return a value?
2. Do I need to set the SearchScope value to be Subtree is I list only 1 OU as the base OU and have it search all sub OUs?
3. Is the string sent in to PropertiesToLoad.Add() generic, or does that need to be a string that is defined by my company?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'd suggest you download http://directory.apache.org/studio/ to eclipse and get to know your directory.  If you have time.  Just in learning how to properly query AD/ldap, most of your questions will get answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) What does the SearchRoot property within DirectorySearcher do? Do I need to set that up to have this query return a value?

It defines the starting point of your search; compare it to a file system - it defines the **starting directory** from which you start your search. You'll be looking inside the `SearchRoot` and possibly you'll be looking at all its child containers. It's just used to reduce the possible number of containers to search for something

> (2) Do I need to set the SearchScope value to be Subtree is I list only 1 OU as the base OU and have it search all sub OUs?

If you want to search OU or other container under your `SearchRoot` - then yes, you have to search the `SearchScope.Subtree` - otherwise the search will only look at your `SearchRoot` container itself (at all the objects like users, computers, groups inside that container - but not at sub-containers).

> (3) Is the string sent in to PropertiesToLoad.Add() generic, or does that need to be a string that is defined by my company?

Those are LDAP attribute names - these can be both, [the standard ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well as possible custom extensions your company might have defined and installed. [Here's a really nice list of all AD attributes as an Excel sheet](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) (several, actually).